# Spring4 MVC not recognizing jsps

Tags: spring-mvc, gradle, jetty, spring-4

I am trying to make an MVC project using gradle and Spring4.

```
@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver() {
  InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
  resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
  resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
  return resolver;
}

...
@RequestMapping("/home")
public String welcome() {
  return "index";
}
```

[image: My Project]

But when I run using gradle jettyRun I get...

```
http://localhost:8080/personal-war/home
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /personal-war/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp. Reason:
  NOT_FOUND
```

**Update Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
  <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.proj.spring.config</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I added this line

```
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

but then only html renders the server side stuff isn't working

Comment: Let's see your web.xml.

Comment: There you go I have included the web.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to know that Servlet containers (I'll assume Jetty too) have a Servlet for rendering JSPs. This Servlet is typically extension mapped to `*.jsp`.

The [Servlet Specification gives the order of `url-pattern` matching](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/)

> 1. **The container will try to find an exact match** of the path of the request to the path  of the servlet. A successful match selects the
>      servlet.
> 2. **The container will recursively try to match the longest path-prefix.** This is done  by stepping down the path tree a directory
>      at a time, using the ’/’ character as a  path separator. The longest
>      match determines the servlet selected.
> 3. **If the last segment in the URL path contains an extension (e.g. .jsp),** the servlet  container will try to match a servlet that handles
>      requests for the extension. An  extension is defined as the part of
>      the last segment after the last ’.’ character.
> 4. If neither of the previous three rules result in a servlet match, the container will  > attempt to serve content appropriate for the resource requested. **If a "default" servlet is defined for the application, it will be used.** Many containers provide an  implicit
>      default servlet for serving content.

In your case, when you forward to

```
/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp
```

The Servlet container will match that path to your `DispatcherServlet` mapped to

```
/*
```

This happens before the container could match the JSP servlet mapped to `*.jsp`.

It therefore uses your `DispatcherServlet` to `service(..)` the request. But your `DispatcherServlet` does not have a handler for

```
/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp
```

The simple solution would be to map your `DispatcherServlet` to

```
/
```

and have it be the fallback `Servlet` if no match is found.

Comment: Strange because it works in an older app using Websphere

Comment: @Jackie Is the `DispatcherServlet` mapped to `/*` or something like `/something-else/*`?

Comment: Nah it is set to /* I use a registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/static/css/").setCachePeriod(31556926); I tried that but it doesn't render JSPs if I try this for the JSP

Comment: Ok so adding /app/* instead got it to work, but I don't really want this. I suppose I could do modrewrite but I would like to avoid this. Can you explain this line a little more "and have it be the fallback Servlet if no match is found."

Comment: @Jackie I have to review the links you posted, but to answer your question. A Servlet  mapped to `/` is considered the "default" Servlet. As you can see in the list of matches, if no other servlet is matched to handle the request, the default servlet will be used. Because it comes in last, a path like `blabla.jsp` will be matched to the JSP Servlet and handled. With `/*` however, that path is matched by the `DispatcherServlet` first, which fails to handle it correctly.

Comment: Gotcha I will look into this a bit further.